# Customize Rails Hash.from_xml with custom conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing, hash

I want to convert my XML document to Hash in Ruby/Rails. Actually, the default conversion by Hash.from_xml in Rails works for me except in one case.

I have a list of items contained in `<item-list>` element, these items can be of different types though. For instance, `standard-item` and `special-item`, each of which has different set of child elements.

```
<item-list>
  <standard-item>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <bar>...</bar>
  </standard-item>
  <standard-item>
    <foo>...</foo>
    <bar>...</bar>
  </special-item>
  <special-item>
    <baz>...</baz>
  </special-item>
</item-list>
```

This XML structure can be confusing for Hash.from_xml as it does not know that both standard-item and special-item are both items and should be in the same level. Hence, from the above XML, the hash generated by Hash.from_xml will be:

```
{ 'item-list' => { 'standard-item' => [ { 'foo' => '...', 'bar' => '...' },
                                        { 'foo' => '...', 'bar' => '...' } ],
                   'special-item'  => { 'baz' => '...' } }}
```

But what I want is to have all items as list members, like this:

```
{ 'item-list' => [ { 'standard-item' => { 'foo' => '...', 'bar' => '...' } },
                   { 'standard-item' => { 'foo' => '...', 'bar' => '...' } },
                   { 'special-item'  => { 'baz' => '...' } } ]
```

Is it possible to extend/customize from_xml so that it performs to way I want to for this case? If it is not possible, what is the best way to achieve this? Given that this is the only element that contains something that deviates from general XML-to-Hash conversion, it does not seem right to me to implement the whole conversion routine where it might have already been implemented for a thousand times.

Another small note, `Hash.to_xml` also replaces all dashes with underscores. Is there a way to prevent this replacement?

Comment: What you have defined here is not a legal hash - you cnanot have two identical keys, because when you call hash['standard-item'] it wouldn't know which to pull, etc. You might want to reformulate this so you get  a two dimensional array, or so that you get an array, wher e'standard_item' is a value inside the subhash?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I forgot to also put in braces around sub-elements in the array. They should be subhashes like what you say.

Comment: You also have a typo in the code. The first `</special-item>` should be `</standard-item>`, instead. (You probably didn't use this exact code to test `Hash.from_xml`, because it causes a parse error.)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior.

```
<a>
  <b>one</b>
  <b>two</b>
</a>
```

Think about how this would be converting to a hash, there cannot be two values assigned to the key 'b'. The only solution is to make the value of 'b' a hash containing an array of 'one' and 'two'.

```
{a => {
  b => ['one', 'two']
}}
```

This is simply how Rails represents XMLs. You will need to check for an array value in the hash, and act accordingly.

Comment: I am aware that this is the correct behavior. However, there is one case where the sub-elements can be of different types and I want them to be in the single array. For instance, let's say that the element "two" is <i> instead of <b>, but I still want the both "one" and "two" to be in the same array.

Comment: After looking at it again, it can work. However you'll probably have to do it yourself with Nokogiri or something similar. I think it'd be easier just to write some code to abstract the Hash's structure so that it treats the elements as if they were on the same level.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is to convert my XML to JSON to be send to a client-side JavaScript. Giving the structure of hash/JSON, I guess the only way to represent the given XML is to use sub-hash?

Comment: If you want to maintain your structure, yes, the JSON format is structured in the same way as the Hash.

Comment: This is also inconsistent because next time you only get one element and the hash value won't be an array anymore. What's with that? Still "correct behaviour"?